# Meteor MongoDB Collection Not Accessible to Meteor publish

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have imported data into a meteor mongodb database. Here is what I did:
With the meteor app running via

> $ yourMeteorAppDir meteor

in one terminal and in another terminal start mongodb running via

> $ mongod

Startup yet another terminal and run the following to import data into your meteor app's database with:

> $ mongoimport -h localhost:3001 -d meteor -c collectionNameHere < jsonFileNameHere.json

However, after importing the documents from the json file I am finding that the collection is not being accessed by my Meteor app. Specifically, when I attempt to publish the collection with:

```
Meteor.publish('collectionNameHere', function() 
   {return collectionNameHere.find();
});
```

I am seeing:

> Exception from sub ci9tk9AsFeyngHWwE ReferenceError: collectionNameHere is not defined
>   I20141203-07:15:18.436(-5)?     at null._handler (app/server/collectionName.js:9:14)
>   I20141203-07:15:18.436(-5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599)
>   I20141203-07:15:18.436(-5)?     at _.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:943)
>   I20141203-07:15:18.437(-5)?     at _.extend._startSubscription (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:769)
>   I20141203-07:15:18.437(-5)?     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:582)
>   I20141203-07:15:18.437(-5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546

I can see the collection in mongo via meteor mongo and can query it via find. Do I need to create the MongoDB collection from the app instead of via an import?

Comment: You need a `collectionNameHere = new meteor.Collection('collectionNameHere')` somewhere available to both client and server.

Comment: Thanks user3557327. I do have that in my: lib/collections/collectionName.js folder

Comment: I may need to change the return collectionNameHere.find() to return collectionNameHere.find({});

Comment: The collection is still not available.

Comment: What I did was reset the MongoDB by 
`$ myApp reset`
and then add the documents a check for the collection and if no docs then insert them from a fixture.js file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new `database_dump.json` in your projects root directory.
2. Then open your terminal and change directory to your projects root directory. For example `cd /var/www/html/meteor/myapp/`.
3. Type `mongoimport --db meteor --collection mynewcollection --type json --headerline --file '/var/www/html/meteor/myapp/database_dump.json' -h 127.0.0.1:3001 --jsonArray`
4. New Mongodb collection

   ```
   // Lib 
   MyNewCollection = new Meteor.Collection('mynewcollection');
   ```
5. Publish your new collection.

   ```
   // Server
   Meteor.publish("mynewcollection", function() {
     return MyNewCollection.find({});
   });
   ```
6. Subscribe to it

   ```
   // Client
   Meteor.subscribe("MyNewCollection");
   ```
7. Have fun with Meteor

Comment: You have to execute `mongoimport` via your terminal(!), not via mongo shell (`mongod`). That's important. :)

Comment: Ron, This is a side project I am working. I have other collections to import from a previous Rails project. I will try this going forward. Thanks for your help.